# Checking if path on Mainframe FTP server is a file or folder.

Tags: java, file, filesystems, mainframe

I have a Java code that transfers file from FTP on Mainframe to my local system . The problem is how do I tell if the given path is a file or folder ? I cannot use the check for extensions as i don't know what the possible extensions can be . Also the following code always returns false ,

```
 fileSystem.isFile("fileName");
```

Being a mainframe filesystem , the path is seperated by `.` instead of `/` and hence a check for `.` at the end also doesnt work.

Again I stream data from the input path to output location using

```
url="connection url of the mainframe"
bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.getInputStream());
```

When I have files at the source path , it writes the content of the file to the destination , and when the source path has a directory it writes the the names and other properties of the files at the directory to the destination.

Sample output when the source is a directory is

```
Name    VV.MM   Created       Changed          Size  Init    Mod    Id
QQQQ    01.00  2009/12/18   2009/12/18 12:15    18    18     0    XXXX 
RRRR    01.00  2009/12/18   2009/12/18 12:16     19     19    0  XXXXX
```

How do I determine if the  source path is a file or folder ?

Comment: Actually this might not be a duplicate question, exact or otherwise.  There are two mainframe file systems, the "Unix file system" and the "classic file system."  The former behaves like "normal" Unix.  The latter does not have directories.  There is some syntactic sugar in the FTP started task that makes it look like you can change directories, but you're really just modifying the qualifier used to subset the datasets you see or create.

Comment: Agreed. The "mainframe" tag blocks the duplication issues. This is a serious question for those who work with FTP where the server is z/OS. I've voted to reopen it, and I request that all the other mainframers who watch this space upvote it as well.

Comment: Thanks @cschneid and @ zarchasmpgmr..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to determine if the path on mainframe is a file or PDS (analogically a directory ) . I used `org.apache.hadoop.fs.ftp.FTPFileSystem` library and the following snippet would work by returning the list of files .

```
FTPFile[] files = ftp.listFiles();
```

Looping through the `files` and checking `file1.isFile()` would suffice. 
Again remember to change to the current working directory before listing the files using  `ftp.cwd(inputPath);`

For an explanation on Mainframe file system please refer to Bruce Martin's answer and the comments that follow. .

Answer (score 2):

I do not have an answer but it sounds like you are acessing Zos. For those who do not
know anything anything about Zos

- Zos **Does not** have **directories**
- What he is calling a directory is probably a PDS (see PDS in [Dataset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_set_%28IBM_mainframe%29)). For those not from a mainframe background, think of it as a type of archive (i.e. jar, Tar, zip etc). This is not a completely accurate description, PDS have some limitations & uses jar files do not, but a jar file is the closest analogy in the PC, *NIX world I can think of.
- How do you detect them - not sure, there may be an file attribute you can access

Comment: z/OS most definitely _does_ have directories. Take a look at z/OS Unix System Services. FWIW, z/OS v1r2 and later conform to the Unix95 product standard: http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/ibm.htm.  Having said that, you are correct when you say "What he is calling a directory is probably a PDS [...]" and your analogy is a good one.

Comment: cschneid, yes you are correct, I tend to forget about Unix System Services - never got to use them & do not quite how Clasic -MVS/ZOS structures map into Unix side of ZOs. Also question is very Clasic -MVS/ZOS. On a side issue, Notice how java uses it jar files, it always reminds me of how load-libraries are used on the mainframe - another case of whats old becoming new again

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of java you are using or if you're using a special library for the host filesystem.

Can you use [java.io.File#isDirectory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) instead?